# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while using coalesce(1)

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm trying to save an rdd by as below,
data.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile(outputPath)

but i'm getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to acquire 76 bytes of memory, got 0

Has anyone faced the similar issue, if so, i would like to learn how did you fix it

Comment: The solution is to not coalesce(1).  If you want a single output file, merge the part files afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

can you please provide of more details on you are getting OOM on driver of executor ?

By the code you posted coalesce(1) will force all executor to send data to a single executor and  if you are data size is huge , you will start seeing failures .

coalesce is resulting in shuffle.  (All mapperTask sending data to a single Task).

Follow http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/understanding-spark-through-map-reduce/ for getting a in-depth understanding